# mysql_pdo for PHP max_execution_time does not work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, amazon-aurora

after switching from php 7.4 to 8.2 this

```
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(5000) */ 
                user_name,
                user_value
            FROM
```

Does not time out anymore after 5 seconds.

I've seen this error report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76048 on pdo_mysql but there doesnt seem to be a solution.
More information:
Mysql- AWS aurora 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.03.1
PDO client API version  mysqlnd 8.2.10

How can I fix or work around this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to set it in session? `set @@max_execution_time = 5000;`?

Comment: What you've shown here is a database hint https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html Nothing to do with PHP or PDO